# Using Gmail API with Xcode 7 & Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, gmail-api

Im trying to follow the guide provided by Google to start using the Gmail API but I'm having troubles following it.

First I had a problem finding

> GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcherLib.a

so I decided to choose the LibGTMSessionFetcher.framework file. Is this right?

I stopped at Step 4: Creating the project because of this

> Create a new iOS > Application > Single View Application project named "QuickstartApp". Set the Language to Swift , and when saving the project set the Add to and Group fields to "QuickStart".

I don't know what they mean by

> set the Add to and Group fields to "QuickStart".

Heres a link to the guide I am using.
[iOS Quickstart | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift)

Any help with this?